# is there a way to do SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() in ADODB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, adodb

```
With rs
    .AddNew ' create a new record
    ' add values to each field in the record
    .Fields("datapath") = dpath
    .Fields("analysistime") = atime
    .Fields("reporttime") = rtime
    .Fields("lastcalib") = lcalib
    .Fields("analystname") = aname
    .Fields("reportname") = rname
    .Fields("batchstate") = bstate
    .Fields("instrument") = instrument
    .Update ' stores the new record        
End With
```

**this is how i am adding records. is it possibel to do something lik ethis???:**

```
With rs
    .AddNew ' create a new record
    ' add values to each field in the record
    .Fields("datapath") = dpath
    .Fields("analysistime") = atime
    .Fields("reporttime") = rtime
    .Fields("lastcalib") = lcalib
    .Fields("analystname") = aname
    .Fields("reportname") = rname
    .Fields("batchstate") = bstate
    .Fields("instrument") = instrument
     SCOPE_IDENTITY()  <----------------
    .Update ' stores the new record


End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have executed the Update command, the identity will be placed in the corresponding field in the recordset. You can read it from there.

Example:

```
id = .Fields("id")
```

Comment: thank you very much. are you sure this is OK in a multiuser environment?

Comment: @I__: Yes, you have an open connection to the table, so the value is read from the actual record rather than by calling a function.

Comment: the answer below says: you can use it, as long as you open your recordset with adOpenStatic ---how do i know if i an opening it this way?

Comment: @I__: The third parameter in the call when you open the recordset is the cursor type, and the adOpenStatic constant has the value 3, so if you use `rs.Open sql, conn, 3` then you are using a static cursor.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

You should make an explicit `INSERT` statement followed by a call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in the same batch.

Comment: @op: yes, though it's not actually about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: are you sure guffa's answer this is OK in a multiuser environment? if so, then why dont i just use it?

Comment: why doesnt this have @ before the values? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: @op: you can use it, as long as you open your recordset with `adOpenStatic`. Your question was about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: im sorry what does that mean adopenstatic?